# Does Sys::Syslog call closelog() for you if your script die()s?

Tags: perl, syslog

This is maybe a point of grammar, but anyhow, just to clarify... [perldoc on Sys::Syslog](http://perldoc.perl.org/Sys/Syslog.html#THE-RULES-OF-SYS::SYSLOG) states:

> The Third Rule of Sys::Syslog is: The program crashes, dies, calls
>   closelog , the log is over.

If 'the program' refers to the whole thing, my script and Sys::Syslog included, does that mean Sys::Syslog does the closelog() calling for me?

If not, does this mean I should put `closelog()` in an END block?

Comment: In the source code there is no such `END` block. The /eg and the /t don't seem to have anything in that regard either. Have you tried it?

Comment: @simbabque, I didn't see any either.  What are the /eg and the /t?  Also I'm not sure exactly what happens if closelog() is not run that would indicate to me whether it worked or not; hence my asking here.  How would you test for it?

Comment: Well, it's a Perl module, even if it's in core. So it's on CPAN. There you can browse it: https://metacpan.org/source/SAPER/Sys-Syslog-0.33 - I don't know a good way to test it unfortunately as I don't really know what it does. Maybe get a clean virtual machine and just try opening the log, writing something and making the program `die`. You'll see what happens. :)

Comment: @simbabque I did look at the source, but I wasn't sure if there was another way it might be accomplishing this.  What are /eg and /t?

Comment: The `/t` directory is where the tests are in the distribution. `/eg` is sometimes there too. It contains examples. See the browse distribution feature on metacpan from the link in my above comment.

Comment: Just call closelog() before you exit for the sake of finickity cleaning up, and if you crash, don't worry about it. Everything will be fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sys::Syslog **doesn't** call `closelog()` on exit. Look at `closelog()` or `disconnect_log()` calls in https://metacpan.org/source/SAPER/Sys-Syslog-0.33/Syslog.pm.

But in most cases it's safe to omit `closelog()` on exit/die in your script: descriptors will be closed on process exit anyway.

*most cases* means cases with ordinary scripts when the Perl interpreter terminates on exit/die of your script. Exclusions are special environments like mod_perl for example: process doesn't exit if your script dies.

Comment: What's meant by 'most cases'?

Comment: 'most cases' means cases with ordinary scripts when the Perl interpreter terminates on exit/die of your script. Exclusions are special environments like mod_perl for example: process doesn't exit if your script dies.